# Re-Symbolizing Proportional Symbols by calling a function in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to re-symbolize normalized proportional symbols to raw proportional symbols on an interactive map (Leaflet)

```
//Step 2: Import GeoJSON data
function getData(map){
    //load the data
    $.ajax("data/PropRaw2001_2013.geojson", {
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            
             //create an attributes array
            var attributes = processData(response);
            var rawAttributes = processRawData(response);

function processData(data){
    //empty array to hold attributes
    var attributes = [];

    //properties of the first feature in the dataset
    var properties = data.features[0].properties;

    //push each attribute name into attributes array
    for (var attribute in properties){
        //only take attributes with population values
        if (attribute.indexOf("Prop") > -1){
            attributes.push(attribute);
        };
    };

    //check result
    console.log("these are the attributes")
    console.log(attributes);

    return attributes;
};

function processRawData(data){
    console.log("Raw data")
    //empty array to hold attributes
    var rawAttributes = [];
    console.log(rawAttributes)
    //properties of the first feature in the dataset
    var properties = data.features[0].properties;

    //push each attribute name into attributes array
    for (var rawAttribute in properties){
        //only take attributes with population values
        if (rawAttribute.indexOf("Raw") > -1){
            rawAttributes.push(rawAttribute);
            console.log(rawAttributes)
        };
    };
```

Here, is the function that will update my proportional symbol size:

```
function updatePropSymbols(map, attribute){
    map.eachLayer(function(layer){
      //Example 3.16 line 4
        if (layer.feature && layer.feature.properties[attribute]){
            //access feature properties
            var props = layer.feature.properties;

            //update each feature's radius based on new attribute values
            var radius = calcPropRadius(props[attribute]);
            layer.setRadius(radius);

            //add city to popup content string
            var popupContent = "<p><b>City:</b> " + props.City + "</p>";

            //add formatted attribute to panel content string
            var year = attribute.split("_")[1];
            popupContent += "<p><b>Population in " + year + ":</b> " + props[attribute] + " million</p>";

            //replace the layer popup
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {
                offset: new L.Point(0,-radius)
            });
        };
    });
};
```

I added two buttons as divs, "normalized" and "raw" which I want the user to be able to use to toggle between normalized raw, using the following function:

```
$("#Normalized").click(function(attribute){
            console.log("normalize function")
            //normalize = true
            //if (normalize = true) {
            
                updatePropSymbols(map, attribute);
            //}
         });
// 
 $("#Raw").click(function(rawAttribute){
            //normalize = false
            //if (normalize = false){
                updatePropSymbols(map, rawAttribute);
            //}
     });
```

However- it's not passing the attribute data through.  It seems like I'm not able to call updatePropSymbols with rawAttribute or attribute (this is normalized).

Answer (score 0):

By using `attribute` and `rawAttribute` as arguments for your click handler functions, you are actually creating new local variables (in this case, they are jQuery [eventObjects](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) describing the `click` event) that will be used instead of the original `attribute` and `rawAttribute` variables. Assuming that you have defined these variables elsewhere, what you want is this:

```
$("#Normalized").click(function(){
  updatePropSymbols(map, attribute);
});

$("#Raw").click(function(){
  updatePropSymbols(map, rawAttribute);
});
```

Here is a simple example illustrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/zhLLydcr/